# Indices of the N smallest elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i am trying to find 3 lowest number from a list and using those indexes to find corresponding value from another list. 
this is an example of what i have tried

```
a = [12, 83, 22, 30, 57, 32, 88, 46, 20, 26, 78, 65, 45, 56, 74]

b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']

lowest = lowest2 = lowest3 =  max(a)

indexes = []

for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i] < lowest :  
            lowest = a[i] 
            print(b[i])

    elif a[i] < lowest2 and a[i] > lowest:  
            lowest2 = a[i]
            print(b[i])

    elif a[i] < lowest3 and a[i] > lowest2:  
            lowest3 = a[i]
            print(b[i])

    print(lowest,lowest2,lowest3)
```

i can only supposed to use anaconda library and no this is not assignment this is a very small part of a program i have been trying to do.

> output: a
>   b
>   c
>   d
>   i
>   j
>   12 20 26

Comment: What is the output of the code you tried? are you getting any error message? Provide this in question

Comment: Does your list always contain unique values?

Comment: yes it does. this was just an example i made. it is usually frequencies present in a signal and other list is tones corresponding.

Comment: I guess you wanted 12, 20, and 22. The corresponding elements are a, i, c.

Comment: yes! that is exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is sort the list `a` and return it's index values,

```
>>> a = [12, 83, 22, 30, 57, 32, 88, 46, 20, 26, 78, 65, 45, 56, 74]
>>> n_min_values = 3 
>>> sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda k: a[k])[:n_min_values] 
[0, 8, 2] # index values
```

and iterate through this index values list to get corresponding values from list `b`,

```
>>> b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
>>> for i in sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda k: a[k])[:n_min_values ]:
        print(b[i])
a
i
c
```

OR

Using list comprehesion,

```
>>> [b[i] for i in sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda k: a[k])[:n_min_values ]]
['a', 'i', 'c'] # your output
```

Answer (score 2):

Heaps are good at doing this sort of thing, especially if the order of the smallest items isn't important.

Here's a small example using `heapq.nsmallest` on `a` with its zipped indices.

```
from heapq import nsmallest
from operator import itemgetter

n = 3
idx, _ = zip(*nsmallest(n, enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1)))
idx
# (0, 8, 2)

[b[i] for i in idx]  # your result
# ['a', 'i', 'c']
```

Comment: I think you can replace that `zip()` with `enumerate()`.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thank you, my python is somewhat rusty :)