# how to get nsmallest non zero values

Tags: python

I am trying to display the three lowest non zero values and the dates they occured

```
Date = ['1-Dec','2-Dec','3-Dec','4-Dec','5-Dec']
Daily_Rainfall_Total_mm = [0,17.5,19,27,2.5]

print("The three lowest daily rainfall is on : ")
print(nsmallest(3, zip(Daily_Rainfall_Total_mm, Date )))
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are?  I don't see any such attempt.  Finding smallest values is well documented.  Exactly where are you stuck?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928509/smallest-n-numbers-from-a-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830504/indices-of-the-n-smallest-elements-of-a-list).

Answer (score 0):

```py
def nsmallest(n, iterable):
    return sorted(filter(None, iterable))[:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store the the month and rainfall in the same Variable:

```
Daily_Rainfall = {'1-Dec':0, '2-Dec':17.5, '3-Dec':19, '4-Dec':27, '5-Dec':2.5}
```

Sort the Dictionary by Value:

```
Daily_Rainfall = {k: v for k, v in sorted(Daily_Rainfall.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

print the first n Days:

```
n = 3
print({key: Daily_Rainfall[key] for ind, key in enumerate(Daily_Rainfall) if ind < n})
```